# Proper way to create a sequence based on multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I'm using Laravel and Migrations to build my entire database structure.

**Problem description**

In schema, I have a `pack` table, that belongs to `user` and `group` and need to keep a kind of unique "index" for each different combination of these tables.

It means: a sequential number that increments based on distinct `user_id` and `group_id`. For example:

```
| id | user_id | group_id | sequence |
| 1  | 1       | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 1       | 2        | 1        |
| 3  | 1       | 3        | 1        |
| 4  | 1       | 1        | 2        |
| 5  | 1       | 2        | 2        |
| 6  | 1       | 3        | 2        |
| 7  | 2       | 1        | 1        |
| 8  | 2       | 2        | 1        |
| 9  | 2       | 3        | 1        |
```

This will be used to references a pack on view layer:

> user 1, this is your pack 1 of group 1.
>
> user 1, this is your pack 2 of group 1.
>
> user 1, this is your pack 1 of group 2.

I designed my migration (on `up`) like:

```
Schema::create('pack', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
    $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('group');
    $table->integer('sequence')->unsigned();
});
```

And use this business logic to fill `$pack->sequence` field on model layer.

**Question 1:**
Theoretically, this should be considered the best strategy to use in described scenario?

**Question 2:**
There's some pattern/approach that can be used to fill `sequence` field on database layer?

Comment: So, you want to make 1,2,3... values on sequence column of the table ?

Comment: @SagarGautam yes, based on different combinations of user & group

Comment: Can you please describe the way in which sequence number should be assigned ?

Comment: @SagarGautam It's already described on question, which point you didn't get?

Comment: Oh I see, Is the sequence you have added in above table is the sequencing you exactly want ?

Comment: @SagarGautam The sequence I've added is my suggested way to "solve" the problem. TBH, I'm not too confident on it. I need a way to get a sequential number for each pack record that increments on each combination of `user_id` and `group_id`. This will be used to references pack on view layer: `user 2, this is your pack 1 of group 3`.

Comment: Little bit confusing and I didn't understand yet, I'm sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

It appears you already have an auto-increment column `id`. MySQL does not support more than one auto-increment column per table.

In general, you can't get the behavior you're describing while allowing concurrent inserts to the table. The reason is that you have to read the max sequence value for some user/group pair, then insert the next value as you insert a new row.

But this creates a race condition, because some other concurrent session could be doing the same thing, and it will sneak in and insert a row with the next sequence value in between your session's steps of reading and inserting.

The solution is to use locks in a way to prevent a concurrent insert of the same user_id and group_id. InnoDB will use gap locks to help this.

Example:

Open two MySQL clients. In the first session, try this:

```
mysql> begin;
mysql> select max(sequence) from pack where user_id=1 and group_id=1 for update;
+---------------+
| max(sequence) |
+---------------+
|             2 |
+---------------+
```

The `FOR UPDATE` locks the rows examined, *and* it locks the "gap" which is the place where other rows with the same user_id and group_id would be inserted.

To prove this, try in the second session:

```
mysql> begin;
mysql> insert into pack set user_id=1, group_id=1, sequence=3;
```

It hangs. It can't do the insert, because that conflicts with the gap lock still held by the first session. The race-condition has been avoided.

Now in the first session, finish the work.

```
mysql> insert into pack set user_id=1, group_id=1, sequence=3;
mysql> commit;
```

Notice after the commit, immediately session 1's locks are released. The second session resolves its blocked INSERT, but it correctly gets an error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1-3' for key 'user_id'
```

Of course, session 2 should have done the same SELECT...FOR UPDATE. That would have also been blocked until it could resolve the lock conflict. Once it resolved, it would have returned the correct new max sequence value.

The locks are only per user_id/group_id combo, *if and only if* you have a suitable index. I used:

```
ALTER TABLE pack ADD UNIQUE KEY (user_id, group_id, sequence);
```

Once you have that key, the SELECT...FOR UPDATE is able to be specific to the right set of rows when it locks them.

What this means is that even if user_id=1, group_id=1 is locked, you can still insert a new entry for any other values of user_id or group_id. They lock distinct parts of the index, so there's no conflict.

I encourage you to do some experiments yourself to prove to yourself you understand how it works. You can do this without writing any PHP code. I just opened two Terminal windows, ran the mysql command-line client, and started writing at the `mysql>` prompt. You can too!